# How do I Set Dynamic List Follows by Dynamic Tab and Fragment in ViewPager?

Tags: android, tabs, android-viewpager

How do I set dynamic list in the dynamic fragment, as I filtered data for the list using viewPager onPageSelect position but not able to set in list View due to sequence problem of fetching data?

My sequence is 
TabSet>ViewPager with Fragment set>Fragmnet OnCreateView>ViewPager.onPageSelect.

But
I'm getting error of Fragment's adapter.notifyDataChange on a null object reference

Can Anyone help me out?

Here is my code:

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ViewPager mViewPager;
    Activity activity = getParent();
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> catList = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> foodItemTitle = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> foodItemTitleList = new ArrayList<>();
    LinkedHashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> titleHashMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    LinkedHashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> fullHashMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    LinkedHashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> halfHashMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    LinkedHashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> qtrHashMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    private String category;``
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        getItemList();

    }

    private void setViewIDs() {
        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(viewPagerPageChangeListener);
        setUpViewPager(mViewPager);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);



    }

    private void setUpViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        SectionsPagerAdapter sectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        for (int i = 0; i < catList.size(); i++) {
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("data", catList.get(i));
            PlaceholderFragment categoryList = new PlaceholderFragment();
            categoryList.setArguments(bundle);
            sectionsPagerAdapter.addFragment(categoryList, catList.get(i));
        }
        sectionsPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        viewPager.setAdapter(sectionsPagerAdapter);
    }

    public void getItemList() {
        final ProgressDialog nDialog;
        nDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        nDialog.setMessage("Loading..");
        nDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        nDialog.setCancelable(true);
        nDialog.show();

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, MENU_ITEM_List, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                try {

                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                    JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("DATA");
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        Model model = new Model();
                        jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        model.setItemCategory(jsonObject.getString("CAT"));

                        model.setItemName(jsonObject.getString("TITLE"));

                        //Getting Item Menu..................................

                        if (titleHashMap.get(model.getItemCategory()) != null) {
                            foodItemTitle = titleHashMap.get(model.getItemCategory());
                            foodItemTitle.add(model.getItemName());

                            titleHashMap.put(model.getItemCategory(), foodItemTitle);

                        } else {
                            ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
                            arrayList.add(model.getItemName());

                            titleHashMap.put(model.getItemCategory(), arrayList);
                        }
                    }

                    category = titleHashMap.keySet().toString();
                    String[] cat = category.split(",");
                    for (int i = 0; i < cat.length; i++) {
                        String strReplaced = cat[i];
                        strReplaced = strReplaced.replace("[", "");
                        strReplaced = strReplaced.replace("]", "");
                        catList.add(strReplaced);
                    }
                    Iterator<String> key = titleHashMap.keySet().iterator();

                    while (key.hasNext()) {
                        String hashKey = key.next();                     foodItemTitleList.add(titleHashMap.get(hashKey).toString());
                    }
                              setViewIDs();

                    nDialog.dismiss();

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    System.out.println("Error in code: " + e.getMessage());
                    nDialog.dismiss();
                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Time Out", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                nDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        RequestQueue requestqueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestqueue.add(stringRequest);


    }

    ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener viewPagerPageChangeListener = new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

        Boolean first = true;

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

            if (first && positionOffset == 0 && positionOffsetPixels == 0) {
                onPageSelected(0);
                first = false;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            Log.v("TabData", foodItemTitleList.get(position));
            String items = foodItemTitleList.get(position);
            new PlaceholderFragment().setItemDetails(items);
       }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    };


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        private ListView listView;
        private ArrayList<Model> dataModelList = new ArrayList<Model>();
        private ArrayAdapter<Model> adapter;

        private final static String TAG = PlaceholderFragment.class.getSimpleName();

        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }


        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_list);


//            setListViewAdapter();

            return view;
        }

        private void setItemDetails(String item) {

            String[] itemStr = item.split(",");
            for (int i = 0; i < itemStr.length; i++) {
                String oneItem = itemStr[i];
                oneItem = oneItem.replace("[", "");
                oneItem = oneItem.replace("]", "");

                Model model = new Model();
                model.setItemTitleFinal(oneItem);

                Log.v("GEtdata", oneItem.toString());

                dataModelList.add(model);
            }
            setListViewAdapter();

            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }

        public void setListViewAdapter() {

            dataModelList = new ArrayList<Model>();
            adapter = new MenuListAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.food_item_list, dataModelList);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }

    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
//                        Log.v("TabData", foodItemTitleList.get(position));
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {

            mFragmentList.add(fragment);

            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {

            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "CharSequence", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            switch (position) {

            }
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }
    }
}
```

This is my adapter:

```
public class MenuListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Model> {

    private Activity activity;

    LinkedHashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> fullHashMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    LinkedHashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> halfHashMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    LinkedHashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> qtrHashMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    ArrayList<String> foodItemTitle = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> priceFull = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> priceHalf = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> priceQtr = new ArrayList<>();

    private String full;
    private String half;
    private String qtr;

    public MenuListAdapter(Activity activity, int resource, List<Model> dataModelList) {
        super(activity, resource, dataModelList);

        this.activity = activity;
//        getItemList();
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder = null;
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        //If holder not exist then loacte all view from UI file.

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.food_item_list, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);


            final ImageButton removeBtn = convertView.findViewById(R.id.img_remove);
            final ImageButton addBtn = convertView.findViewById(R.id.img_add);
            final TextView spinnerItemQuanty = convertView.findViewById(R.id.spinner_item_quantity);
            final TextView totalPrice = convertView.findViewById(R.id.total_price);
            final TextView item = convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_name);

            final ViewHolder finalHolder = holder;

            removeBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {


                    String currentQnty = spinnerItemQuanty.getText().toString().trim();
                    int qnty = Integer.valueOf(currentQnty);
                    qnty = qnty - 1;

                    if (qnty >= 0)
                        spinnerItemQuanty.setText(String.valueOf(qnty));
                }
            });

            addBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    String currentQnty = spinnerItemQuanty.getText().toString().trim();
                    int qnty = Integer.valueOf(currentQnty);

                    spinnerItemQuanty.setText(String.valueOf(qnty + 1));

                    String title = item.getText().toString();

                    customPopUp(title);
                }
            });


            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        Model model = getItem(position);

        holder.itemTitle.setText(model.getItemTitleFinal());

        return convertView;
    }

    private void customPopUp(String title) {

        final AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.price_popup, null);
        dialogBuilder.setView(dialogView);

        TextView itemName = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.popTitle);

        Button cancel = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.cancel_order);
        Button select = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.add_order);

        itemName.setText(title);

        final AlertDialog alert = dialogBuilder.create();
        alert.show();

           }

    public void getItemList() {
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, MENU_ITEM_List, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                try {

                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                    JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("DATA");

                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                        Model model = new Model();

                        jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                        model.setItemName(jsonObject.getString("TITLE"));


                    }

//                    nDialog.dismiss();

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    System.out.println("Error in code: " + e.getMessage());
//                    nDialog.dismiss();
                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Time Out", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
//                nDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        RequestQueue requestqueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());
        requestqueue.add(stringRequest);


    }


        }

    private static class ViewHolder {
        private TextView itemTitle;
        private Spinner spinnerItem;
        private ImageButton removeBtn;
        private ImageButton addBtn;
        private TextView spinnerItemQuanty;
        private TextView totalPrice;

        public ViewHolder(View v) {

            itemTitle = v.findViewById(R.id.item_name);
            spinnerItemQuanty = v.findViewById(R.id.spinner_item_quantity);
            totalPrice = v.findViewById(R.id.total_price);
        }
    }

}
```

Here is list of title filtered according to category:

**Category:** [MORNING SPECIAL,  DESSERT & ICE CREAM,  CHINESE]

**Food ITEMS:** [[Tea, Puri Sabji, Samosa, momos], [ROSOGULLA, Softy], [Chicken Tandoori, Chicken Korma]]

I am trying to add food items to list but array adapter getting null data because onCreateView set first then I am getting data from onPageSelect that's why my application get crashed down.

Comment: Can Anyone Reply Me?

Comment: Now I don't need anyone's answer. I have solved it. lolz